# HTACCESS - Setting root folder as public_html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So, I'm currently writing my .htaccess file, and I've stumbled upon the issue of root folders. Currently, `http://localhost/public_html/index` is the root of my website. What I want to do is have the url as `http://localhost/index` instead.

I know this is pretty simple, but all of the posts I have looked at so far have not proven to work. Here is what I have so far, which is producing a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/$1 [QSA]
```

Please include any documentation or guides to .htaccess itself if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just move your site up to the document root?

Comment: It would, but I'm wanting to do it through htaccess as I have other directories inside of the `http://localhost/` domain...

Comment: Okay, but you make those inaccessible to the web with your second rule that rewrites all requests to go to the `public_html` directory.

Comment: Hence why I am asking for help in writing my .htaccess

Comment: You haven't really made it clear what you want to happen. Should files in `public_html` shadow those in the root or the other way round. Conflicts can occur so you have to pick an order of precedence.

Comment: What I want is the following: The files that are in `http://localhost/public_html` (such as about.php, home.php, etc), should be accessed through typing `http://localhost/about.php`, rather than `http://localhost/public_html/about.php`

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. You are saying `public_html` should take precedence over the root?

Comment: Yes, because there are no files in the root directory that users will be open to viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following .htaccess code can be added to achieve the results wanted:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public_html/
RewriteRule (.*) /public_html/$1 [L]
```